# (3) In Bubble, how to trigger workflows using url parameters?

Tags: bubble.io

please select the correct answer.

1 first use "data to send" and then check the url using "when the page is loaded"

2 first use "send current page parameter" and then check url using "when page is loaded"

3 first use "send more parameters" and then check url using "when page is loaded"

4 first use "send more parameters" and then check url using "Do every 5 seconds"

which one is correct?

Comment: This is not even a question ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228358/why-are-my-questions-on-stack-overflow-getting-downvotes-without-explanation